# What are the supported clients and client versions for Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

What are the supported clients and client versions for Oracle Autonomous Database?

Answer (score 1):

Any connection type supported by Oracle Net Services can be used to connect to Autonomous Database.

Oracle Call Interface (OCI) connections require installing the Oracle client software. For these connections, Oracle Database Client 11.2.0.4 (or higher) or the Oracle Instant Client 12.1.0.2 (or higher) are supported by Autonomous Database.

For JDBC Thin connections, the only requirement is to have JDK8 (or higher) installed.

You can also connect to Autonomous Database using the Oracle supplied tools such as [Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html) (version 18.2 or higher recommended)and [Oracle SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html).

Some of these clients and tools such as JDBC, SQL Developer, and SQlcl support TLS authentication without using any wallet; hence making life much easier as opposed to mTLS authentication, which requires a wallet. I definitely recommend checking out the TLS option without a wallet in ADB since it has several advantages as described in [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/post/connecting-your-autonomous-database-has-never-been-easier).

Another great option is Oracle Database Actions if you don't want to worry about supported versions, installing a client, whether to use a wallet or not. Database Actions is a web-based interface that uses Oracle REST Data Services to provide executing your SQL statements and scripts, creating Data Modeler diagrams, developing RESTful web services, managing JSON collections, and using the Data Load, Catalog, Data Insights, Business Models, and Data Transforms tools to load data from local and remote sources, view data in your tables and views, view objects in your data dictionary, and organize, analyze, and transform your data. You can access Database Actions from the ADB details page of your instance in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure console:

[image: Database Actions]

I also recommend referring to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connect-preparing.html#GUID-3667EC68-930E-4566-95B3-DFA24203A8FF) for more details on supported clients, client versions, and connection methods.

Disclaimer: I’m a Product Manager at Oracle.

Comment: +1 for valuable information. Great blog post! Is mTLS+TLS configuration supported from oci-cli and terraform?

Comment: @BjarteBrandt Thanks! Yes, both are supported:

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/3.3.1/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/db/autonomous-database.html

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/terraform-provider-oci/4.52.0/docs/d/database_autonomous_database.html